# Как найти все первые объекты в mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-jpa

Как найти в коллекции все первые вхождения по массиву?
У нас имеется массив условных ID-шников, необходимо в коллекции найти первый элемент с таким ID, а затем перейти к следующему ID. Это необходимо для уменьшения количества обращений к БД

В качестве решения может быть обычный запрос в mongoDB

```
anyIds = [5faa2f1f3fb224704009fe3e, 5faa2f233fb224704009fe3f, ..., 5faa2f233fb224704009fe40]
```

На выходе

```
List<MyObj> fromDB = [myObj1, myObj2, ..., myObjN]
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста [небольшой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) входных данных, чем заполнить коллекцию и массив этих ID-шников, и что ожидается на выходе. Так будет гораздо проще для отвечающего, меньше будет возможных итераций.

Comment: @mrEvgenX добавил в вопрос, но, я думаю, что не особо важно чем. тут по сути принцип нужен, конечно можно сделать N-обращение к БД и получать их по запросу `findFirstByAnyId(String anyId)`, но это будет большое к-во обращений к базе